# ReactJs Lazy loader

Tags: reactjs, lazy-loading

I'm new in ReactJs.

I need a lazy loader in my application when page is scroll down,
I'm using (https://jasonslyvia.github.io/react-lazyload/examples/#/normal?_k=rz3oyn)

Actually, this is working fine but first time it load all data.

I want to make api call and set data when page will scroll down.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably what you need is an infinite scroll functionality. There are some good options for React when it comes to loading asynchronous data:

1) If you need high performance (a lot of results coming from the server) you can try [react-infinite](https://github.com/seatgeek/react-infinite). As docs say:

> React Infinite solves this by rendering only DOM nodes that the user
>   is able to see or might soon see.

2) Another simple option would be: [react-infinite-scroller](https://github.com/CassetteRocks/react-infinite-scroller)

General principle to make these libraries work is to pass their props which will let the module know when to make a request or when to wait.

```js
<InfiniteScroll
    pageStart={0}
    loadMore={loadFunc}
    hasMore={true || false}
    loader={<div className="loader">Loading ...</div>}
>
    {items} // <-- This is the content you want to load
</InfiniteScroll>
```

`loadFunc` will make an API call to the server and will set hasMore to false until it is successfully resolved.

Comment: See also `react-virtualized` it seems to be more actively maintained lately (2017) on Github. It can calculate dynamic, varying row heights on-the-fly.  https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized